# Pandas generating an empty csv while trying combine all csv's into one csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a python script that will read all the csv files in the current location and merge them into a single csv file. Below is my  code:-

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = os.getcwd()
extension = csv
os.chdir(path)
tables = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))
data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in tables:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(r''+path+'/'+i+'')
        # Here I want to create an index column with the name of the file and leave that column empty
        df[i] = np.NaN
        df.set_index(i, inplace=True)
        # Below line appends an empty row for easy differentiation
        df.loc[df.iloc[-1].name+1,:] = np.NaN
        data = data.append(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
 data.to_csv('final_output.csv', indexx=False, header=None)
```

If I remove the below lines of code then it works:-

```
df[i] = np.NaN
df.set_index(i, inplace=True)
```

But I want to have the first column name as the name of the file and its values NaN or empty.

I want the output to look something like this:-
[image]

Comment: remove the `try/except` block. is it raising errors?

Comment: `indexx=False` is a typo

Comment: also, setting the index on blank column is a strange practice. what are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped it here @Paul H. I removed the try except block as well it did not give any errors

Comment: print `df.shape` with each iteration. Are you sure your files have data?

Comment: i printed data.shape and its showing me (24,14). Also tried by removing the index=False but still getting an empty csv file

Comment: something is missing from your example, e.g., `extension = csv` should raise a ValueError

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid the `.append` method in favor of `pandas.concat`

Try this:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

files = Path(os.getcwd()).glob('*.csv')

df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(f).assign(filename=f.name)
    for f in files
], ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('alldata.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I do not want the whole column filename to be populated. It should be present just in the first row of each dataframe. Thats the purpose I am trying to use 'df[i] = np.NaN'

Comment: could you provide more context? why does it only need to be on 1 row? presentation?

Comment: please check the screenshot that I want the result to be like

Comment: @ShashishekharHasabnis I understand what you want, but I'm asking what the motivation for that is. This sounds like an X-Y problem: http://xyproblem.info/